# Best way to outline a geology map in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I have a geology map where I have to outline lines of different styles (dotted, or solid), and eventually I have to fill arbitrary enclosure of these lines (so e.g., sometimes I need to fill a shape enclosed partly by solid and partly by dotted lines), what would be the best way to do this in inkscape?

I'm thinking of defining the paths for filling the colors and then later copying them and breaking them for the line displays (dotted, solid, etc.) but are there better ways?

Comment: Interesting question, can you tell something about your efforts? Have you searched on the net (for example [here](https://blogs.otago.ac.nz/si-geology/training-for-staff-and-students/digitising-a-hand-drawn-map-using-inkscape/) and [here](http://runswithrocks.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/geology-mapping-with-qgis-and-inkscape/))?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this isn't particular to geology maps. So maybe change the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a better way, I'd like to know it myself. As I'm doing this kind of thing -- creating shapes with an none-uniform outline -- quite often.

Ctrl-D creates duplicates a shape *in its exact place*. So I usually create the shape first with a fill colour and no outline. Then I duplicate it and work on the copy that is now on top.

I set an outline and remove the fill colour. If I need to split the path exactly at it's bezier points, I do so with the path editing tool, then I uncombine it with Ctrl-Shift-K. If I need to split it elsewhere, I do so by creating what I like to call 'scissor path' and split with Path -> Cut Path from the menu.

Comment: @user287001 Your edit doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. Don't get me wrong: It may be exactly what the OP needs. But _I_ don't see how it relates to the question. However, being new here, I'm inclined to leave it at that.

Comment: Hm. And downvoted. I don't think I understand Stackexchange ...

Comment: No downvote, only removed my upvote.. But I put it back, because actually the receipe is usable as is.

Comment: Ah, okay, removing an upvote in this context at least makes sense.

Comment: This looks like the best way so far (and was indeed roughly what I did eventually...)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is *Fill Bounded Areas* (the paint bucket), which still needs solid lines to work as you desire, but you need not combine them or similar.

Note however, that this tool does not yield precise results. You can avoid some of the problems though by making your lines very thin initially.